# AppleScript Cocoa application without main Wiindow

Tags: user-interface, command-line, applescript

Im trying to create Apple Script Cocoa app in Xcode but with somehow odd behaviour: I dont want to show any GUI to the user. Essentially its command-line application written in AppleScript. I suppose I need to get rid of Main Window and manage event loop. 
Any pointers directions are highly appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do this in the AppleScript Editor App? There wouldn't be any GUI if you wrote it as an App in Automator.

Comment: I need .app bundle which I must sign with Dev ID. Application is executed via command line and shall not display any GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Just Delete the Window on the AppDelegate.xib BUT DONT DELETE THE AppDelegate.xib file and in the AppDelegate.applescript you can make the script in the

```
applicationWillFinishLaunching
```

Area

Eg.

```
script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"

    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
       -- Put your script Here       < --------------- Script Here
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

end script
```